# ChromeDriver - Can't login to google account

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. Chrome Version 83.0.4103.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)
3. selenium ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39

and simple C# code which just open google login page

```
        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "https://accounts.google.com/";
        Console.ReadKey();
```

When I type email for login I see the message "Couldn't sign you in" and one of the reasons for that error "Use automation testing frameworks" which I am using.

[image]

What to do with that?

Duke

Comment: This is a protection by google itself, so you need to either use a existing chrome profile

Comment: "use an existing chrome profile"? Now sure what you mean. How to do it?

Comment: I found the solution here. All you need to do - set the same profile folder which you using for default. options.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=c:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\");